# sending a string from php to javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

Im tring to pass a string which im getting from my database to a javascript function.

In my php I have:

```
<input type="image" name="edit_me" id="edit_me"  value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onClick="edit_chirp(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)"/> //THIS WORKS
```

When I pass the id im getting it works fine but when I pass a field where it has text it doesnt work.

```
<input style="float:right" type="image" name="edit_me" id="edit_me"  value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onClick="edit_chirp(<?php echo $row['content']; ?>)" //THIS DOESNT WORK
```

My javascript function is

```
function edit_chirp(somethig)
    {
        alert(somethig);
    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work, are there any errors?

Comment: Nope..nothing happens

Comment: Console says nothing? What about the rendered HTML, what's it show?

Comment: Maybe you have got "quote" characters in your string too ?

Comment: but when I pass the id, the id that I send is alerted

Comment: Maybe 'content' is a text, then you must include quote like onClick="edit_chirp('<?php echo $row['content']; ?>')"

Comment: There are no quotes in the characters...just simple characters with spaces

Comment: @EMADSEYED And that's why it doesn't work. Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and you'll see the error.

Comment: You have an XSS hole.

Comment: I'm also noticing that in your broken example, you're not closing your input tag with `/>`.

Answer (score 1):

You have been missing quotes dude. 
Try this

```
<input style="float:right" type="image" name="edit_me" id="edit_me"  value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onClick="edit_chirp('<?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($row['content']); ?>')" //THIS WILL WORK
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't work "perfectly"---it'll break as soon as there are apostrophes in the content or if someone decides to inject malicious JavaScript there.

Comment: @Juhana yep you are right. He can use mysql_real_escape_string for this

Comment: @shadow That's not the right function for this case. At all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add simple quotes in the function call for the parameter. Something like this :

```
<input style="float:right" type="image" name="edit_me" id="edit_me"  value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onClick="edit_chirp('<?php echo $row['content']; ?>')"
```